# InputBox bloquear CTRL+V

Tags: delphi, input, delphi-7

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
vResultado := InputBox(Application.Title, 'Leia o cartão de Segurança:', '');
```

Existe uma forma de bloquear o copiar e colar no InputBox?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Acredito que não exista algo assim para o `InputBox`.
Você pode criar seu próprio `InputBox`e com isso você vai poder definir os eventos que quiser.
Neste caso criamos uma unit nova, que vai ser nossa classe, com um método principal do tipo class (class function) chamado InputBox. Segue o código a baixo:

```
unit Unit2;

interface

type

  TCustomInputBox = class
  private
    class procedure EditKeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
  public
    class function InputBox(const ACaption, APrompt, ADefault: string): string;

  end;

implementation

uses
  Vcl.Forms, Vcl.StdCtrls, System.Types, System.UITypes;

{ TCustomInputBox }



class procedure TCustomInputBox.EditKeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
  if (Key = #22) then
    Key := #0;
end;



class function TCustomInputBox.InputBox(const ACaption, APrompt, ADefault: string): string;
var
  Form: TForm;
  Prompt: TLabel;
  Edit: TEdit;
  DialogUnits: TPoint;
  ButtonTop, ButtonWidth, ButtonHeight: Integer;

  IsValid: Boolean;

begin
  IsValid := False;
  Form   := TForm.Create(nil);
  with Form do
    try
      ClientWidth  := 350;
      ClientHeight := 85;
      Canvas.Font  := Font;
      BorderStyle  := bsDialog;
      Caption      := ACaption;
      Position     := poScreenCenter;
      Prompt       := TLabel.Create(Form);
      with Prompt do
      begin
        Parent   := Form;
        Caption  := APrompt;
        Left     := 10;
        Top      := 10;
        WordWrap := True;
      end;
      Edit := TEdit.Create(Form);
      with Edit do
      begin
        Parent     := Form;
        Left       := Prompt.Left;
        Top        := Prompt.Top + Prompt.Height + 5;
        Width      := Form.Width - 24;
        Text       := ADefault;
        OnKeyPress := EditKeyPress;
        SelectAll;
      end;
      ButtonTop    := Edit.Top + Edit.Height + 25;
      ButtonWidth  := 75;
      ButtonHeight := 25;
      with TButton.Create(Form) do
      begin
        Parent      := Form;
        Caption     := 'OK';
        ModalResult := mrOk;
        Default     := True;
        SetBounds(Form.Width - 180, 60, ButtonWidth,
          ButtonHeight);
      end;
      with TButton.Create(Form) do
      begin
        Parent      := Form;
        Caption     := 'Cancel';
        ModalResult := mrCancel;
        Cancel      := True;
        SetBounds(Form.Width - 90, 60,
          ButtonWidth, ButtonHeight);
      end;
      if ShowModal = mrOk then
      begin
        Result := Edit.Text;
      end;
    finally
      Form.Free;
    end;
end;

end.
```

A partir dai, basta usa-lo em qualquer lugar do seu projeto:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TCustomInputBox.InputBox(Application.Title, 'Leia o cartão de Segurança:', '');
end;
```

Lembrando que os demais bloqueios também podem ser implementados, Ex: Ctrl+C, Ctrl+X, Botão Direito + Colar ...

Comment: Victor +1, estou sem acesso ao Delphi nesse momento, mas... acredito que seja possível modificar a `InputQuerry` nativa, digo, adicionar a ela o evento `KeyPress` personalizado! A `InputBox` esta escrita na `Vcl.Dialogs`, da uma olhada depois!

Comment: @JúniorMoreira, mexer no código do Delphi não seria legal. O que eu andei pensando, é criar um Helper pra esse cara, o que acha ? No momento estou sem tempo, assim que conseguir eu vejo se funcionaria.

Comment: Editei a resposta criando uma classe especifica para o InputBox, isso vai facilitar na utilização do método. Alem disso, ajustei para funcionar com o InputBox, e não mais com o InputQuery.

Comment: Pronto, mais simples e funcional. Sobre mexer no código do Delphi, realmente "não é uma boa prática" mas para diversos casos é ate melhor!

Answer (score -2):

// Para bloquear o CTRL+V no campo,
use o codigo abaixo no eveno "KeyDown" do Edit
(obtido em https://delphi.cjcsoft.net/viewthread.php?tid=43113)
//

```
if ((ssCtrl in Shift) AND (Key = ord('V'))) then
begin
  //if Clipboard.HasFormat(CF_TEXT) then ClipBoard.Clear;

  edit1.Text := 'Não Pode _(*~*)_';

  Key := 0;
end;
```

Answer (score -3):

é simples, no evento `KeyPress` do seu `input`, você coloca o seguinte código

```
if (Key=#22) or (Key=#3) then Key:=#0;   // 22 = [Ctrl+V] / 3 = [Ctrl+C]
```

Comment: Acho que não existe o evento KeyPress, por por se tratar de um InputBox

Comment: Simples, cria um novo formulário e adiciona nele um input.